# using value of enum in g:select when enum is attribute of selection object

Tags: grails, select, enums, gsp, scaffolding

Example:

batchTag is an enumerated type attribute of a batchRange, with values like so:

```
JAN1 "January Biweekly 1",
JAN2 "January Biweekly 2",
```

etc.

I want to display the VALUE of the batchTag in the select, IOW, the select should contain

```
"January Biweekly 1"
"January Biweekly 2" ...
```

not

```
JAN1
JAN2
FEB1
FEB2
FEB3 ...
```

I have tried several things in the g:select to do this, but without any success.  I thought perhaps "it" would be available as part of the g:select (as it is clearly an iteration) and tried to reference it.batchTag.name for the optionValue, but that did not work.  Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
enum BatchRange {
    JAN1 "January Biweekly 1",
    JAN2 "January Biweekly 2",

    final String value

    BatchRange(String value) { this.value = value }

    String toString() { value } 
    String getKey() { name() }
}
```

Note the getKey() method.  And then your g:select

```
<g:select name="batch" from="${BatchRange.values()}" optionKey="key" />
```

or

```
<g:select name="batch" from="${BatchRange.values()}" keys="${BatchRange.values()*.name()}" />
```

Comment: Thank you! The second suggestion is what I sought.

Comment: The first tag-solution can be simplified to `<g:select from="${BatchRange.values()}" optionValue="value" />`.
Then you don't need the BatchRange toString- or getKey-methods either.

Comment: @Gregg, I am getting the following error: `...No signature of method: static BatchRange.values() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: use([Ljava.lang.Object;), use(java.lang.Class, groovy.lang.Closure), use(java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure), save(), evaluate(java.io.File), evaluate(java.lang.String)` Any suggestions?! Thanks.

Comment: @AlwaysANovice you have to create a groovy enum type under src/groovy

Comment: @AlwaysANovice : This syntax worked for me :  `CREEE('Créée'), LANCEE('Lancée'), TERMINEE('Terminée')`. see https://grails.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Enum%20usage

Comment: Thank you @Alex and BenC for the help

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use i18n messages in this case. There are two options:

1. Add valueMessagePrefix to the select.
2. Make the enum implement `org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable` as described in [this blog post](http://adhockery.blogspot.se/2009/03/internationalizing-domain-classes-and.html).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7571808/1737590) for further information.