# How to implement a dropdown list from the domain class in grails

Tags: grails

In my grails project i want to implement a drop down list.
As we define,
 String priorityType in the domain class,

it generated as a normal text field to input data.
I want to know how define stage as a dropdown list which would contain premium, bold as its drop down values
If can please help me for this

Comment: this link shows how to create a dynamic dropdown list http://java.dzone.com/articles/grails-dynamic-dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual dropdown used for relations. Create a domain `PriorityType` and define instead of `String priorityType` reference to this domain `PriorityType priorityType`.

In other case you can create a dropdown from enum values. Here the example:

```
 <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: shoppingCenterInstance, field: 'activityState', 'error')} required">
    <label for="activityState">
        <g:message code="shoppingCenter.activityState.label" default="Activity State"/>
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:select name="activityState" from="${ActivityState?.values()}"
              keys="${ActivityState.values()*.name()}" required=""
              value="${shoppingCenterInstance?.activityState?.name()}"/>
</div>
```

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126340/using-value-of-enum-in-gselect-when-enum-is-attribute-of-selection-object) how to use select+enum

Comment: can we use enum eg:class Category{
  Type type
  enum Type{
    GENERAL, BOLD
  }
}

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126340/using-value-of-enum-in-gselect-when-enum-is-attribute-of-selection-object how to use enum