# Grails translated enum

Tags: java, grails

After checking [Enum in Grails Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046624/enum-in-grails-domain) and following the tutorial, I don't get the translated values for my enum.

```
static final enum ActivityType implements MessageSourceResolvable {
        TRAINING,
        COMPETITION

        public Object[] getArguments() {
            [] as Object[]
        }

        public String[] getCodes() {
            [ name() ]
        }

        public String getDefaultMessage() {
            "activity.type." + name()
        }
}
```

and my select looks like

```
<g:select
    name="type"
    from="${ClassActivity.ActivityType.values()}"
    value="${classActivityInstance?.type}"
    class="chzn-select form-control"
    noSelection="${['': '-']}"
/>
```

while my `message.properties` contains

```
activity.type.TRAINING = Training
activity.type.COMPETITION = Competition
```

I expect my dropdown to contain "Training" but instead I get `activity.type.TRAINING`. Have I missed something?

Comment: this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126340/using-value-of-enum-in-gselect-when-enum-is-attribute-of-selection-object